# CGRectOffset position will reset for UIButtons when title of button is updated

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, offset, cgrect

thats strange but..

So i change Y position of 2 UIButton via CGRestOffset and all is ok, position is some as you can see.

```
odometervalue.frame=CGRectOffset(odometervalue.frame,0, offsetYPosition);
        units.frame=CGRectOffset(units.frame,0, offsetYPosition);
```

But when i update title for UIButton units or UIButton odometervalue then offset position is reset for both elements. I cannot understand why.

Comment: Are you using auto-layout?

Comment: Yes i use auto layout

Comment: then try setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES; for the buttons

Comment: Thank you so much. but always when i set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES showing message in log 

2015-10-09 19:50:24.330 app[2520:355234] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
 Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property tra...

Comment: But any way. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question was to use:

```
translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
```

for buttons.

As for the error, it states that one of the constraints can not be satisfied, and that is probably due to the fact that you have moved your button. I do not know sure how to exactly point you to the constraint that is causing problems, but try starting from the constraints connected to the button, and his sub/superviews.